# How to update author's detail of comments in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to update the `displayName` and `email` of commenters within google sheet using `Spreadsheet` Service along with `Drive` service.

I have used both `Drive.comments.patch(comments, fileId, commentID)`, `Drive.comments.patch(comments, fileId, commentID)` to achieve the same, The script runs successfully but no effect within the  google sheets and doesn't change anything of comment

```
function maskComment() {
  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var FileID =currentSpreadsheet.getId()
  var commentsList = Drive.Comments.list(FileID)

  //No effect in any of this, however the debugger lists both setDisplayName and setEmailAddress 
  commentsList.items[0].author.setDisplayName("company user"); 
  commentsList.items[0].author.setEmailAddress('test@mycompany.com');

  //No effect in any of this but code runs successfully
  Drive.Comments.patch(commentsList.items[0], FileID, commentsList.items[0].commentId) //or Drive.Comments.update(commentsList.items[0], FileID, commentsList.items[0].commentId)  No
}
```

I will appreciate any further information regarding changing  `email` and `display name` of commenter within google-sheets.

Comment: When I saw the official document of [Resource representations for Comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments#resource), only `content` is `writable`. And, `author` has no `writable`. From this situation, I think that `author` cannot be modified by patch and update methods in Drive API. I apologize for this.

Comment: As said by @Tanaike `author` can not be changed. But maybe you could create a new comment and deleting the old one? Could a workaround of that kind be usable to you? The `author` would be seen as the user that made the request but you can overcome that with [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)